# Projection onto binary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I've tried googling this but maybe this is a problem that is called something else by people in the field because it turned up absolutely nothing.

I am curious about the problem of projecting a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{B}^n$) onto a $k$-dimensional binary subspace $(k<n)$. Any references would be nice (other notations for the problem, for instance).

Comment: What is a `binary` subspace?

Comment: If $u,v \in A$, then $u+v \in A$ where $+$ is modulo 2.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: So it looks like "binary" is a property of the underlying *field*, rather than of the subspace. This is called $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are you in $\mathbf R^n$ or in $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)^n$?

Comment: I guess we're in $\mathbb{F}_2$ then, thanks for commenting. This is a new field to me, no pun intended.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: Hahahaha!

Comment: When you project in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it's usually understood that you're projecting orthogonally, with respect to the ordinary scalar product. To project, you need not only the subspace you're projecting onto, but also the direction of the projection (parallel to a subspace supplementary to the one you're projecting onto.) In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we always take the orthogonal complement. (For example, for a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the direction of planes perpendicular to that line.) In the case of $F_2$, it's not clear what you intend to have stand in for this concept of orthogonality.

Comment: @David thanks for the comment, I guess in $F_2$ a projection would be equivalent to finding $x$ minimizing Hamming distance, which I guess there does exist a lot of literature for, but it's not denoted "projection".

Comment: Okay. It's not immediately clear to me whether this is an example of projection in the linear algebra sense. Do you know of instances in which multiple points can be selected that minimize the Hamming distance? If so, then this is separate from the usual notion in linear algebra.

Comment: Right right, the minimizer defining projection is only guaranteed to be unique if the set is convex! That hadn't occured to me.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, subspaces *are* convex. What would convex mean in $F_2^n$ anyway? Lines only have two elements. Even if you were talking about $F_3$, there would be no ordering to say what it meant for a point to be *between* two others.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying.